# Installing PHP 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and getting errors

Tags: php, ubuntu

I trying to compile PHP7 on Ubuntu 14.04 but getting errors after running this command

```
./configure \
--prefix=$HOME/php7/usr \
--with-config-file-path=$HOME/php7/usr/etc \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-zip \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-exif \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-wddx \
--with-curl \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-iconv \
--with-gmp \
--with-pspell \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--with-t1lib=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-gd-jis-conv \
--with-openssl \
--with-mysql=/usr \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr \
--with-gettext=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--with-bz2=/usr \
--with-recode=/usr \
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

I followed these insctructions:

[enter link description here](http://www.zimuel.it/install-php-7)

The errors are:

http://pastebin.com/DD05uEeJ

Hope you can help guys.

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: sorry updated it :)

somewhy the script cant find directories or the commands. But if i followed instruction should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the backslash at the end of each line isn't really at the end of each line (based upon the errors).

You might want to try copying and pasting it (from your own question) again and it should work properly.